# Como detectar cambios con @input value Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hola tengo el siguiente Componente hijo que recibe un objeto de tipo dia mediante el @input

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,OnChanges,SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import { TiempoService } from './../../services/tiempo.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-graphs',
  templateUrl: './graphs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graphs.component.css']
})

export class GraphsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() dia:any[] =[];

  public barChartOptions:any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };
  public barChartLabels:string[] = [];
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

  public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [], label: 'Temperatura'},
    {data: [], label: 'Humedad'},
    {data: [], label: 'Cobertura Nubosa'}
  ];
  constructor() { 
    console.log(this.barChartData);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.dia.length; index++) {
      this.barChartData[0].data.push(+this.dia[index][7]);
      this.barChartData[1].data.push(+this.dia[index][15]);
      this.barChartData[2].data.push(+this.dia[index][12]);
      this.barChartLabels.push(this.dia[index][6]);
    }
    console.log(this.dia);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes.dia);
}
}
```

sin embargo este valor cambia dependiendo del componente padre, implemente el metodo ngOnChanges para notificarme cuando ocurran cambios, el console.log del metodo ngOnChanges (currentValue) efectivamente cambia el valor dependiendo del cambio en el componente padre, pero como podria hacer para renderizar denuevo el componente y que se vuelvan a setear las nuevas variables cuando el objeto dia cambie de manera que se actualize la vista dinamicamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
@Input() set día(_dia: any[]): void {
    for (let index = 0; index < _dia.length; index++) { 
        this.barChartData[0].data.push(_dia[index][7]);
        this.barChartData[1].data.push(_dia[index][15]);
        this.barChartData[2].data.push(_dia[index][12]);
        this.barChartLabels.push(_dia[index][6]);
    }
}
```

De este modo se ejecutará el código del setter cada vez que a tu componente llegue un nuevo valor. Alternativamente, puedes ejecutar el consigo en tu `ngOnChanges`, pero en ese caso deberías comprobar cual es el input que ha variado y ejecutarlo solo en caso de que sea el día.

Comment: Hola @IIsanchez, gracias por tu respuesta, te comento que ya fui capaz de actualizar los arreglos this.barChartLabels, barChartData, cada vez que se ejecuta el metodo set dia, pero que haria falta para que se renderize dinamicamente en la vista html?

Comment: Tendrías posibilidad de colgar algo mas de código? tal vez en https://stackblitz.com o algo asi? De todos modos, echa un vistazo a este ejemplo https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-properties-change-detection?embed=1&file=src/main.ts y a este articulo https://ngdev.space/angular-2-input-property-changes-detection-3ccbf7e366d2 por si pudiese ayudarte de algun modo. Y, si tu variable `barChartData` se usa en la plantilla para renderizar algo, es posible que no funcione al utilizar el método `push`

Answer (score 1):

Hola ya logre solucionar el problema, primero que todo habia que llamar el metodo set cada vez que se generara un nuevo valor de _dia: any[], tal cual como lo explica @Ilsanchez, ademas investigando un poco resulta que es la mejor opcion cuando se tienen pocas variables que cambian, es por esa razon que no se implemento el metodo ngOnChanges,

```
 @Input() set dia(_dia: any[]) {
    this.barChartLabels = Object.assign([], []);
    this.barChartLabels.length = 0;
    this.barChartData[0].data.length = 0;
    this.barChartData[1].data.length = 0;
    this.barChartData[2].data.length = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < _dia.length; index++) {
      this.barChartData[0].data.push(_dia[index][7]);
      this.barChartData[1].data.push(_dia[index][15]);
      this.barChartData[2].data.push(_dia[index][12]);
      this.barChartLabels.push(_dia[index][6]);
    }
  }
```

este metodo efectivamente se ejecuta cada vez que la variable cambia sin embargo esta no modificaba la vista ya que se tenia una misma referencia al objeto barChartLabels, la solucion en este caso fue utilizar Object.assign([], []); que cambia la referenia del objeto y angular sera capaz de renderizar la vista con los nuevos cambios.

Comment: Perfecto, en ese caso, marca tu respuesta como correcta para que pueda ayudar a otros con el mismo problema. Por otro lado, como buena practica, procura tratar las propiedades internas de tus componentes como inmutables para que la detección de cambios de angular funcione correctamente. Por ejemplo, en lugar de utilizar `push` que muta el array sobre el que se llama, es preferible usar `concat` que devuelve una nueva instancia.